How can I recreate my Firebase Authentication users with different UIDs?
I have an application that handles authentication with the firebase-authentication service. Due to some recent changes in business logic, I need to start storing my users in a Mongo database as well. So, I must migrate the users to my Mongo database but in addition, I need them in Firebase to have the UID corresponding to the one generated by Mongo. Since I can't change the firebase UID (if I'm wrong please correct me), my plan was something like this:

Get all registered users in firebase
Create these users with the additional information in mongo
For each user created in Mongo, also create it in Firebase, using the Mongo ID as the UID.
Delete old firebase users

However, my plan has a delicate detail. I understand that I cannot obtain firebase passwords, so when deleting and creating users, I would have to generate new passwords for all users. How can I address this situation to avoid this?

Why can't you use the user ID generated by Firebase as the key in Mongo?

The flow is already deployed and there are already users in mongo saved with the ID as object id, so we must have integrity. (Using the firebase UID would imply saving strings and not object ids in mongo)

You can't get the password from Firebase indeed. In fact, if you ever encounter a service that allows you to retrieve a password, you should stop using that service immediately - as that's a huge security risk.
What you can get from Firebase though is the password hashes and the algorithm+salts used to determine those, which you can then use to implement the same algorithm elsewhere and get the new sign-in flow working with the same credentials.
Firebase doesn't allow you to set the salt+hash for users in its built-in providers though. So if you want to implement this flow, you'll have to implement your own auth provider. This is quite involved, so you might want to consider keeping a mapping table from the mongo ID to the Firebase UID instead.

Just out of curiosity, how can I get the password hashes and the algorithm+salts in Firebase?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-export or https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#password_hashes_of_listed_users

Very interesting, I just tried it and it actually works, I didn't know that could be done. Just to confirm, then I can't try to save users with those hashes and salts directly? By the way, the hash and salt field appear, but not the algorithm used.

Check the docs; there might be a default (scryp iirc).
